# Java jar manifest file with unrecognized fields

Tags: java, java-9, java-platform-module-system, manifest.mf

I am working on migration my application to java9, I found that I can set `Add-Opens` in my manifest file to open some java internal packages for reflection usage. I am thinking fields like `Add-Opens` are only support after java9, so I wonder what will happen if I run it using lower version like java8. Will those unrecognized fields (general unrecognized fields not specific to `Add-Opens`) in the manifest file be ignored in java8? What impact they can have on the application when running on java8? Thank you.

Comment: Specifically for Add-Opens, I think the security functionality that manifest entry enables in modern JVMs is essentially the default behavior in 8 (i.e. you can already do reflection and call private methods, etc)

Comment: The [java.util.jar package documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/jar/package-summary.html) links to [the manifest specification](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/specs/jar/jar.html#notes-on-manifest-and-signature-files), which states:  “In all cases for all sections, attributes which are not understood are ignored.”

Comment: Just note that the Add-Opens manifest attribute only works when your whole application is a single jar and you start it by using `java -jar`

Comment: @ThiagoHenriqueHupner, I think as long as I am using java -jar to run the executable jar it doesn't have to be a single jar right. It can have classpath folder outside jar, we just specify that in our executable jar's manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for VGR's comment, this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/specs/jar/jar.html#overview) for oracle official document on manifest states that `Attributes which are not understood are ignored. Such attributes may include implementation specific information used by applications.`

Reference: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/specs/jar/jar.html#overview

Comment: In your specific case, it might be helpful to know that [Java 8’s policy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#Manifest-Overview) was already the same.